# Updating CSV file in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, csv

How can I update a csv-file in cartoDB?

When a csv-file is loaded into cartodb, it might contain errors in the data. E.g. some fields partially contain a wrong formtted date.

After having cleaned up the error in the data, how can this file be 'reloaded' to cartoDb? Especially with keedping the maps and settings.

This is not the question about regularly updating input data.

Comment: Not sure to understand your issue. CartoDB doesn't store CSV files. Your data is stored as database tables. You can import and export from/to CSV files, though. Can you elaborate a bit more your question?

Comment: OK, you're right. It's about reloading csv-files into the DB-tables. But just for correcting data, not regular updates. 
Let's assume, I loaded a csv-file and found out later that a date-field is not consistently formatted. So e.g. not all row's could be read a valid date (simply because there are some additional blanks and comma's in the field). So I’m going to correct the data (in the csv-file) and need to reload the file into the table again to use it with the already established settings (thereby avoiding that a new file has to be loaded and all settings been defined again).

Comment: In the mean time I found out that there is a possibility to do a synch-data with Dropbox, but this is not exactly what I am looking for, as I don't need to do the reload on a regular basis.

Comment: I see the issue. The problem is that once you add a layer to a map, the relation is "persisted" so if you re-upload your dataset as a new table you can't remove the previous dataset without removing also the map because of this link. What I sometimes do is to add an empty dataset to my map and then update manually the SQL, so if my dataset needs to be swapped on the map (and afterwards removed), my map won't be affected. This is a common issue and the team is aware of it, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the clarification. It's simply good to know that something is not available and avoid to search hours for 'nothing'.
Can you take your comment as answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pasting from a comment

I see the issue. The problem is that once you add a layer to a map, the relation is "persisted" so if you re-upload your dataset as a new table you can't remove the previous dataset without removing also the map because of this link. What I sometimes do is to add an empty dataset to my map and then update manually the SQL, so if my dataset needs to be swapped on the map (and afterwards removed), my map won't be affected. This is a common issue and the team is aware of it, sorry for the inconvenience